# need help saving my stuff on my laptop

Tags: iphone, damage

So my iPhone 6 broke completely still turns on but the screen is totally cracked cant see anything and I have a lot of stuff saved on it I tried saving them to my laptop but my phone is locked how can I unlock it to get get my stuff off I basically only need an alternative way to unlock it. I have a windows laptop

Comment: do you have itunes on that windows laptop

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I think that Apple has gone to where you have to enter in the unlock code in order to backup, update, etc. with iTunes if the device was powered down. Even with iTunes, they would likely need to be able to somehow enter the unlock

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://discussions.apple.com/message/21852561#21852561

> PLfrompasadena
>
> Jul 31, 2014 9:35 PM 
>   **Re: Is there a way to unlock an iphone with a non-responsive touch screen?** in response to Princesscheena I am posting this solution
>   hoping that it will help others.   My son dropped his iPhone5C and the
>   screen is cracked.  One small area still works, but he couldn't enter
>   his passcode and therefore couldn't sync with iTunes to backup the
>   iPhone before giving it to someone to repair.   I searched online and
>   most people said it couldn't be done. However, in this particular
>   situation I was able to log in.  Essentially, I was able to turn on
>   the VoiceOver mode and that allowed me to use the small area of the
>   screen that still functioned. In VoiceOver mode, you swipe left/right
>   to highlight different keys on the screen that can be selected by
>   double-tapping.  Step by step, this is what I did:
>
> - Hold Home key to turn on Siri, told Siri to 'Turn on VoiceOver'
> - Press Home key to get to main unlock screen
> - Swipe right/left until 'Slide to Unlock' is selected
> - Double tap Now the passcode page comes up
> - Swipe right/left to highlight the correct keys on the keyboard and double tap to 'enter' each one.
> - Swipe to highlight enter/done and double tap to submit the passcode. Once the iPhone was unlocked, the first thing I did was backup the
>     phone and download all the photos.   Hope this helps people.   Phil

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Apple ID, you can use your fingerprint to unlock your iPhone 6. Are you able to interact with your screen?